# How was dnsmasq answering DNS queries before I fixed /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-interface, dnsmasq

I installed dnsmasq to provide both DHCP and DNS on my home network. Everything was working swimmingly until just now.

Seemingly out of the blue I was unable to connect to the internet on any computer on my network. Nor could I connect to the computer running dnsmasq by hostname.

I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was wrong. I tried restarting the computer. I tried restarting dnsmasq. I checked the dnsmasq syslog entries and I noticed that, after restarting dnsmasq, dnsmasq was complaining about */var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf* being empty. That seemed weird.

I checked */etc/network/interfaces*, several times, and finally I noticed that the stanza for the relevant interface in my file was slightly different than an example I saw online.

Here's what I had:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I changed the last line to this:

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

and *almost immediately* after I restarted the interface, DNS requests were working again.

How was dnsmasq working before I changed the *interfaces* files?

Comment: "How was dnsmasq working before I changed the interfaces files?" how exactly was he working? Could it resolve hostnames?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell now but there may have been an older `resolv.conf` setting that was overwritten in response to some random event that happened recently. That would've broke DNS which you then fixed by enabling the system to re-populate that file with the correct information.

Comment: @Braiam dnsmasq was resolving hostnames, both private and public.

Comment: How do you know it was dnsmasq doing the resolving in the past? If `/etc/resolv.conf` had a `nameserver 192.168.1.1` line, resolving would have worked fine, bypassing dnsmasq altogether.

Comment: @wurtel I'm pretty sure it was dnsmasq because it was resolving hosts in the private domain on my network. *192.168.1.1* is a router, tho before I setup dnsmasq it was providing DHCP and DNS, tho it was ultimately unreliable at resolving hosts in the private domain. I was also logging DNS queries received by dnsmasq and observed requests – particularly all of the ones for which I was having problems – in syslog.